# Share Java test helpers classes across different kinds of test modules in Gradle project

Tags: testing, gradle

I have two kinds of tests: unit and integration tests. I would like to have another one in which I would like to place more complex test cases. Each kind of test is placed in different module.

Bellow I am placing a piece of project structure to make it a little bit more visible

```
...
---buildSrc
------build.gradle(1)
------gradle.properties
---src
------main (files with production code)
------integration-test
------test (files with unit tests)
------new-test
------build.gradle(2)
...
```

**My goal:**
I have already created plenty of test helpers which are placed in integration-test module and I would like to reuse them in new-test module.

This is how looks like my sourceSets in build.gradle(2) file:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    }
    newTest {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/new-test/java'
            srcDirs 'src/integration-test/java'
        }
        resources.srcDir file('/src/new-test/resources')
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output + integrationTest.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output + integrationTest.output
    }
}
```

And thanks for that (srcDirs 'src/integration-test/java') I am able to use sources from integration-test in new-test module but I have serious doubts if it is a proper way to do that because I am getting a communicate from Intellij:

```
Path [C:/Repositories/my-project/project/src/integration-test/java] of module [project.newTest] was removed from modules [project.integrationTest]
```

This is my newTest task from build.gradle(2) file:

```
task newTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform() {
        excludeEngines "junit-vintage-engine"
    }
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.newTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.newtTest.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

And this is my configurations section from build.gradle(2) file:

```
configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime

    newTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    newTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
```

I have already looked into following tutorials:

1. [Multi-project test dependencies with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle) (I have only one project and here it is shown how to share test
   classes between projects)
2. [How to share test classes across Gradle projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814812/how-to-share-test-classes-across-gradle-projects)
3. http://michaelevans.org/blog/2019/09/21/stop-repeating-yourself-sharing-test-code-across-android-modules/ (I can't currently migrate to Gradle 5.6)
4. [Include tests from other module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754005/include-tests-from-other-module)

So what can I do to use test helpers from integration-test module in new-test module? I would like to also separate those helpers classes into separate module and then my new-test and integration-test tasks could take it as a test dependency.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new project (eg test-lib) for the test helpers/utilities. Put the sources in `src/main/java` in the test-lib project then depend on test-lib wherever you need it